# How do I shutdown a Linux box without running init 0

Tags: linux, shutdown

I want to shutdown my computer as if power was cut off (don't ask me why). How do I do this under Linux?

Comment: Pull the power plug? :)

Comment: And you know that there's a difference between "init 6" and cutting the power off?! You should decide which of your two questions you want to be answered.

Comment: @Bryan:  Won't work on a laptop, so you'd also have to remove the battery.

Comment: I meant init 0. I can't edit the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your system has it, the poweroff command should do it:

```
poweroff -n -f

  -n = don't sync
  -f = don't run shutdown
```

Comment: Interesting, but my `man` page for `poweroff` doesn't list `-n` (not that it's needed).

Comment: My man page for `poweroff` does list these options :-). Debian squeeze/stable.

Comment: I get `Failed to reboot: Operation not permitted` as root.

Answer (score 7):

you can echo 'o'  (poweroff) to /proc/sysrq-trigger:

```
$ echo o | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Comment: This is one of the better options if your hard disks failed. In such a case, you'll get an I/O error running the poweroff command.

Answer (score 6):

you could just panic it, depending on what you wish to achieve.

```
sysctl -w kernel.panic=1
```

Comment: That's even better than I had in mind.

Comment: I get `sysctl: setting key "kernel.panic": Read-only file system`

Comment: @AlexejMagura Are you in a docker container or other unprivileged environment?

Comment: @TomMD I'm running a docker image inside of kubernetes.

Comment: @AlexejMagura Then you can't write to most (all?) of sys for security reasons.

Comment: @TomMD Unfortunately, yes.